# Specifying a newer C++ standard library dependency for a Debian package

Tags: c++, debian, packaging, libstdc++, deb

I am completely new to Debian packaging and the documentation I've found takes either the form of really-incomplete tutorials (with overly-specific examples), or encyclopaedic-style manuals (with scant examples). From these, I'm trying to piece together how to package some C++17 code -- which I do not control -- to make it easier to install downstream. The target machines run Debian Buster, whose stable GCC is v8.3. This isn't new enough, so I have to install GCC 10 from `testing` on the build machine.

How do I reflect the updated requirement for `libstdc++` in a Debian `control` file? Is this enough:

```
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 10.2.1)
```

The version here is quite arbitrary (it's one I know to work); is `libstdc++6` even right? How does one indicate that this package comes from a different source?

Comment: Easy to indicate app compiled with the bullseye  g++-10 as it depends on `libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.28` . ..... How to use with Debian Buster : libstdc++.so.6.0.28 must be present. I.e. point to  `libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.28` to start the app. ...... Version overview https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that:

```
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 10.2.1)
```

...is enough and Apt will just complain and refuse to install until you have manually added a source that provides that package. Thanks to @KnudLarsen's comment, the *actual* minimum version I needed was 9.1.0.